# NSDate causing 2GB of memory allocation

Tags: objective-c

I have a timer that updates labels in my program and the timer pauses when ever there a user interaction such as finger down or scrolling occurs. I'm using this code to fix it and it works, but it seems to be re-creating memory allocations causing the game to crash within minutes.

```
-(void) timeChangerInitNormal {
    if (running == YES)
        if ( _timerQueue ) return;
    _timerQueue = dispatch_queue_create("timer queue", 0);

    dispatch_async(_timerQueue, ^{

        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(timeChanger) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        while ( [timer isValid] ) {
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:5.0]];
        }
    });
}


- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
{
    [self _lockInteraction];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
{
    [self _unlockInteraction];
}
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view
{
    [self _lockInteraction];    
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale;
{
    [self _unlockInteraction];
}

- (void) _lockInteraction
{
    [self _setControls:_staticViews interacted:NO];
    [self _setControls:_autoLayoutViews interacted:NO];
}

- (void) _unlockInteraction
{
    [self _setControls:_staticViews interacted:YES];
    [self _setControls:_autoLayoutViews interacted:YES];
}

- (void) _setControls:(NSArray *)controls interacted:(BOOL)interacted
{
    for ( UIControl *control in controls ) {
        if ( [control isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) {
            control.userInteractionEnabled = interacted;
        }
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self _updatePositionForViews:_autoLayoutViews];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self _updatePositionForViews:_autoLayoutViews];
}

- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
{
    return _mapImageView;
}
```

Comment: On which kind of iOS-device are you having 2GB of RAM at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr

You just want to use a normal timer. After creating it add it to the event tracking mode:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode];
```

This will make it trigger while tracking events (touch down on slider, scroll view, ...).

In case you still want to know: You created a thread that basically kept a CPU busy spinning in the while loop, creating autoreleased `NSDate` objects. Since there was no inner autorelease pool the date objects were not released.

But don't try to fix you old code. There are more issues.